# How to force using gzip with the PLYLoader of three.js?

Tags: three.js

I'm using the PLYLoader of three.js library to load a pointcloud in .ply format and the file size is about 8-10MB and it seems that it doesn't use gzip so it loads all 10MB of data.

I wonder if there would be the possibility to use gzip for the file transfer because manually compressing the .ply pointcloud I reduce the size to 2-3MB.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't use gzip? Sounds like a problem about the configuration of your server hosting the .ply file, not a three.js problem. What kind of server is it?

Comment: @Volune I'm using Tomcat 8 with the default configuration. And I check whether it uses gzip looking at the "Network" tab of the Chrome developer tools, comparing the file size and the download size.

Comment: Using the network tab, can you check if the request header `Accept-Encoding` contains `gzip`, and show us the request and response headers ? (Don't need to publish host and cookie headers) (Just to make sure if it's client-side or server-side problem)

Comment: @Volune Sure, the `Accept-Encoding` of the request is `Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch` and the response header is `Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:10026186
Date:Sat, 06 Sep 2014 11:34:07 GMT
ETag:W/"10026186-1408409096304"
Last-Modified:Tue, 19 Aug 2014 00:44:56 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1` . I may add that currently I'm testing this on localhost, maybe that could ignore the gzip?

Comment: The Tomcat 8 default configuration probably has gzip compression disabled (which is understandable because most of the time gzip compression is done by a front server like apache/varnish/nginx/...). You can have a look at [this article](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/) or tomcat documentation to enable compression.

Answer (score 3):

I have used pako for that, a very fast zlib library for javascript:

https://github.com/nodeca/pako

Works like this for gzipping:

```
var deflate=new pako.Deflate({gzip:true});
deflate.push(data,true);
var ndatagzBlob = new Blob([deflate.result]);
```

and like this for ungzipping (it will find that data is gzip from the header):

```
var inflate=new pako.Inflate();
inflate.push(new Uint8Array(this.response),true);
var data=inflate.result.buffer;
```